# Changing colors of ngx-echarts charts

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, colors, ngx-echarts

How to change the colors of all kind of charts in ngx-echarts?

Ive tried (html): `<div echarts [options]="chartOption" [theme]="colorScheme" class="demo-chart"></div>`

(ts):

```
colorScheme = {
    domain: [
      '#2FDF75',
      '#246EB9',
      '#BCD3F2',
      '#323031',
      '#FBFFF1',
      '#CCFF90',
      '#FFFF8D',
      '#FF9E80'
    ]
  };
```

The colors do not change. I am afraid that the format of my custom theme is not the right one. I couldnt find any documentation on how to change the colors of the charts in an easy way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the **color** property in the option

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-your-component',
  templateUrl: './your-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./your-component.component.css']
})
export class YourComponent {

  chartOption: any;

  constructor() {
    this.chartOption = {
      color: ['#2FDF75', '#246EB9', '#BCD3F2', '#323031', '#FBFFF1', '#CCFF90', '#FFFF8D', '#FF9E80'],
      // your other chart options...
    };
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div echarts [options]="chartOption" class="demo-chart"></div>
```

example link [click..](https://xieziyu.github.io/ngx-echarts/#/basic/basic-usage)

hope it helpful..

Comment: Thank you! That worked! Much easier than I expected.